# How to change color of tab when pressed?

Tags: apex, visualforce, tab, custom-view

I have designed custom detail-views using Visual-force to show on clicking custom tabs. 
I want to change the color of the tab when selected.
[image]

As you can see in this picture, Here I have clicked on tab **Relationship Management**. On this, I want to change the color of **Relationship Management** tab, But when i click on this tab, **Home** tab is focused and it is looking like we have clicked **Home** Tab.

I am using this code to open a custom view on clicking this particular tab,

**My Custom-Tab' Object properties are:**

[image]

**And My Custom-tab properties are:**
[image]

**My visual-force Code is:**

```
<apex:page controller="RelationshipManagement_ApexClass" >
<apex:form id="RelationshipManagementForm">
    <apex:commandButton action="{!GoToLeads}" value="Leads" id="Leads_Link" style="background:YellowGreen; height:30px;"/>&nbsp;
    <apex:commandButton action="{!GoToContacts}" value="Contacts" id="Contacts_Link" style="background:YellowGreen; height:30px"/>&nbsp;
    <apex:commandButton action="{!GoToAccounts}" value="Accounts" id="Accounts_Link" style="background:YellowGreen; height:30px"/>&nbsp;
    <apex:commandButton action="{!GoToOpportunities}" value="Opportunities" id="Opportunities_Link" style="background:YellowGreen; height:30px"/>&nbsp;
    <apex:commandButton action="{!GoToClient_Relationship}" value="Client Relationships" id="Client_Relationships_Link" style="background:YellowGreen; height:30px"/>&nbsp;
</apex:form>
```

Any way to do this? 
Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add tabStyle attribute in you visualforce page

```
<apex:page controller="RelationshipManagement_ApexClass" tabStyle="Account" >
```

Instead Account use your sobject API Name .

Or if it is VF page tab

then `tabStyle="VFPageTabName__tab"`

You need to add your VF page Tab name here and append the `__tab`

Comment: I have checked it out. But it only removes focus from Home tab, means Now home tab is also has same color as other tabs have, but selected tab does not change its color.

Comment: I want to change color of selected tab as Home tab have in attached screenshot.

Comment: @KhawajaM.Awais Yes I got your point. You need to check the your VF page Tab API Name.. Use that in `tabStyle` attribute. I guess it will `Relationship_Management` and you need to use `tabStyle="Relationship_Management__tab"`. Check the VF page tab name is it correct or not ? if you don't specify the correct one it will take the home

Comment: @KhawajaM.Awais is it resolved?

Comment: It is giving me error that "Invalid tabStyle 'Relationship_Management__tab' specified."
If I remove "__tab" from tabStyle, It is giving me error "Invalid tabStyle 'Relationship_Management' specified.  If you are trying to reference a custom Visualforce tab, you must append '__tab'."

Comment: @KhawajaM.Awais that will be `Relationship_Management__tab` don't remove the __tab

Comment: Then same error message is shown to me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40871/discussion-between-ratan-and-khawaja-m-awais).

Comment: @KhawajaM.Awais can you just open your visualforce tab info and take a screenshot and add in your question. ? let me check what is the correct api name of your visualforce tab name ?